# Set property of Page on Response.Redirect("Page.aspx")

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using `ASP.NET 3.5` with `C# 2008`.

I have a master page in which I have a grid view that have `ItemCommand` event. This master page has two child pages `Page1.aspx` and `Page2.aspx`.

Now, `Page1.aspx` has two division let us say `div1` and `div2`.

By default `div1` is `visible` and `div2` remains `hidden`.

Now, the requirement is when I `redirect` to `Page1.aspx` from `Page2.aspx`, I want `div1` `visible`. While, when I click any button from `MasterPage's gridview`, the `ItemCommand` event will be fired and that also will redirect me to `Page1.aspx` but at that time I need to show only `div2` and want to make `div1` hidden.

I can pass query string on `ItemCommand` event while redirecting to `Page1.aspx` using `Response.Redirect("Page1.aspx?DisplayDivTwo=true")`, but I `don't` want to follow such approach. Any other solution? I tried to set property before redirection but it is not working.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from Session and Querystring you can also use the `Server.Transfer` feature. You can then store the data in the `Request.Items` property of your page. They will be there on the page you're transferring to.

Alternatively you can [use the Server.Transfer feature in combination with the `PreviousPage` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx) in your aspx page.

MSDN has a pretty long article on all the options avialable to you. See:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw(v=vs.100).aspx

And of course you can use a [Single Page Application javascript framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336450/javascript-spa-frameworks-single-page-application) to build the concept of pages in the client side, but actually only server one page from the server. You can then handle all the data going back and forth through json services.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and +1 for the detailed information. But if I use Server.Transfer then the URL will remain the same i.e. of previous page. So that it can create confusion to user that the name and tab visible to him is different from showing in URL. FYI, in my web application there are limited number of users and are technical persons. So I need to take care about the URL also displayed to which page they are.

Comment: Why would a technical person be concerned with the page url :). They should understand that the url doesn't matter. That aside, if you need to update the URL you'll need to use cookies, session or url parameters. Or you'll need to update something in your backend/database which reflects the choice of the user. Be really careful with these techniques and tech savvy users, they usually work with multiple tabs which can cause all kinds of issues when you don't do this right.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following approach

1.Using Query String (Which is already implemented by you)

2.Using Session Variables

You are using asp.net better to use multi-view instead of Divs

Comment: +1 for giving better idea to use multi-view instead of Divs. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

So you want to pass data to another page without using query strings?

you can use session state

```
Session["DisplayDivTwo"]=="true"
```

and in your page1 page load

```
if(Session["DisplayDivTwo"]!=null)
string display= (string)Session["DisplayDivTwo"];
```